# How to custom Zend Framework 2 Logger structure?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to custom my logger file in zend framework 2, I config file **global.php** as bellow:

```
return array(
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory', 
    ), 
),
'log' => array(
    'Log\App' => array(
        'writers' => array(
            array( 
                'name' => 'stream',
                'priority' => 1000, 
                'options' => array( 
                    'stream' => 'data/logs/'.date('Y-m-d').'-event.log',                            
                ), 
            ), 
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

And I had a logger file with structure as :

> **2014-06-27T04:29:24+02:00 INFO (6): Load index action sucess!**

How can I custom logger structure become :

> **No:1    Date:2014-06-27   Time:09:36:35   Content: Load index action sucess!**

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should use Formatters

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.log.formatters.html

You can customize it to your needs using the parameters $format & $dateTimeFormat, or create your own class.

In this case, probably the best option is base on **Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple**.

and overload just only this line

```
const DEFAULT_FORMAT = '%timestamp% %priorityName% (%priority%): %message% %extra%';
```